# Ruby features and their benefits while scripting

Tags: ruby, linux, scripting

I see that Ruby is a big success when it comes to web programming. However, for desktop applictions and scripts, I do not see it being heavily used. In fact, in most of the Linux distros, it does not come installed by default. Most applications are coded in Python and some are in Perl. What advantages can Ruby offer over Python when it comes to desktop applications and scrips? If i am writing one Linux application, say a music player, how Ruby blocks and metaprogramming techniques can help?

Edit:
I see that some have opted for close this question because it can escalate into a Language war, perhaps. Fear not, I am a day-time Python programmer. I am trying to reconcile these seemingly incompatible observations. It is fact that most Linux distros do not come with a ruby installed. It is also a fact that most Linux apps are coded in Python. And it is also a fact that Ruby has more advanced meta-programming features than Python, which can make development easier. I am wondering why Ruby is not used as much in Linux application development, which has been a playground for scripting languages.

Comment: Both Python and Ruby (among others) have good support to write any type of applications. It's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: I write non-web scripts in Ruby almost 99% of the time. It's a great language for back-end tools, and is becoming essential for our infrastructure.

Comment: I work in an office where non-web Ruby scripts drive a huge amount of automation. It has, as the Tin Man says, become essential here.

Comment: @SonySantos, though all languages are nice and equal is a politically correct statement to make, it is simply not true. Otherwise we all would be programming in Assembly. Language features exist for some reasons, most of the time, it is to make development easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has become popular on the Linux side because many distributions have built their various front-end tools using it so it's guaranteed to be available.

Ruby does have Qt bindings that might be what you're looking for and it's possible to write wrappers for any C or C++ library you need to interface with.

In the end it all comes down to finding a suitable example to learn from. You may find that there are far more Python examples to refer to and this may affect your decision.

Both languages are equally capable on the whole and the default distributions are similar in terms of performance. Python's new [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) compiler is faster if you don't mind sticking to Python 2.7, and there's also [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) which is an effort to boost Ruby's performance.

Comment: I have an issue with this statement that both are equally capable. I am a day-time Python programmer. Metaprogramming is generally not used in Python as much as Ruby. Also, lambdas in Python are used for very simple callbacks unlike blocks in Ruby. Generally Python is used in a straight-forward way with little magic unlike Ruby. My question is how metaproframming and other advanced ruby features can help desktop developers.

Comment: Metaprogramming, which is really just a form of functional programming, is not as useful in the desktop domain because the toolkits do not support it. Most of the ones I've seen use an event-driven model which procedural languages like C and C++ are better suited to. Both Python and Ruby are functionally similar, though you may find functional programming a lot less messy in Ruby. At the end of the day, though, implementation strategy is driven by tool support.